# Meteor and Template undefined after updating to 1.2

Tags: meteor

Just upgraded my project to 1.2 and ran it, suddenly my console output looked like this.

[image]

I've tried adding/removing some packages but nothing seems to be working and I can't seem to think of any compatibility issues that I could have caused by migrating.

here is my package list as well

```
accounts-password        1.1.3  Password support for accounts
blaze-html-templates     1.0.1  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with  Meteor Blaze
check                    1.0.6  Check whether a value matches a pattern
dburles:google-maps      1.1.4  Google Maps Javascript API v3
ejson                    1.0.7  Extended and Extensible JSON library
iron:router              1.0.9  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
jquery                   1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
logging                  1.0.8  Logging facility.
materialize:materialize  0.97.1  Materialize (official): A modern responsive    front-end framework based on Material Design
meteor-base              1.0.1  Packages that every Meteor app needs
mobile-experience        1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experience
momentjs:moment          2.10.6  Moment.js (official): parse, validate,   manipulate, and display dates - official Meteor packaging
mongo                    1.1.1  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
random                   1.0.4  Random number generator and utilities
reload                   1.1.4  Reload the page while preserving application state.
rzymek:fullcalendar      2.3.1  Full-sized drag & drop event calendar (jQuery plugin)
session                  1.1.1  Session variable
spacebars                1.0.7  Handlebars-like template language for Meteor
standard-minifiers       1.0.0  Standard minifiers used with Meteor apps by     default.
tracker                  1.0.8  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a problem related to the latest version of `materialize:materialize@0.97.1` which breaks the entire Meteor app.

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2037

Until a fix is available, you must stick to version `0.97.0` this way :

```
meteor remove materialize:materialize
meteor add materialize:materialize@=0.97.0
```

The `@=` syntax will force Meteor to keep this version even when you `meteor update`.

Comment: You are a life saver! I thought it was iron router messing stuff up. Didn't think it would be the css framework!

Comment: You save my life, too! Thanks

Comment: hate to keep adding more 'thanks', but this was *very* not self-evident. Thanks stackoverflow SEO for making this more searchable than the gh issue!